# deleting files in a given subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a few subdirectories in a given folder, where a file d2.sh~ exists. I want to delete this file via following shell script, which, rather than writing in a .sh file I wrote on terminal, on one line. [**Edit:** been formatted properly here for clarity]

```
for i in `ls *`; do
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        cd $i
        rm d2.sh~
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

This did not give me any errors but it failed to delete `d2.sh~` from the subdirectories. So I want to know what mistake I have made above?

Comment: It's impossible to know the problem without seeing the list of files that `ls *` puts out. However, that really is irrelevant as you should not be doing that in the first place (see link in my answer)

Comment: In general, do not attempt to cd and then cd back.  Instead, run the command in a subshell: "( cd dir; cmd; )".  (In this particular case, don't cd at all; just call rm with a relative path from the current dir.)

Answer (score 6):

```
find /some/path -type f -name "d2.sh~" -delete
```

Your first mistake is trying to parse `ls`. See [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as to why.

Just use `for i in *; do ...`.

If you need recursion then you need to look to `find` or if you have Bash 4.X you can do:

```
shopt -s globstar; for i in **/d2.sh~; do rm "$i"; done
```

Comment: I know the above command but I want to know  mistake in my shell script.

Comment: @RegisteredUser - the answer here explains that "the first mistake [well, the first mistake is the approach you're taking, but in any case] is trying to parse 'ls'".  That is the problem. Type `ls *` and what do you get? => `file1 file2 dir: file3` (note the ":" after the directory).  Get rid of the `ls`, and just use `for i in *` (as recommended). To debug scripts, add in `printf...` (`echo`) statements in your script so that you *know* what the value if "$i" is in your loop, and add `#!/bin/bash -x` (the "-x" option, for debug) to your script to print out the exact lines being executed.

Comment: for that matter, given what is actually trying to be accomplished, simply do:  `rm */d2.sh~` (or `rm */*/d2.sh~` or whatever) and skip the whole looping thing (ignoring err msgs if no files found). But `find` is useful for (of course) finding files, but do note some of the actions (e.g., "-rm" or "-delete") and restrictions (e.g., -maxdepth) may not be portable. Nonetheless, you can still do something like:  `for x in $( find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*~" -print); do ...; done` or simply (summarizing): `rm $( find ... )` (it's still ok if no files are found, ignore the err msg)